# THERMODO scheme

Tags: микроконтроллеры

Нашел одну интересную штуковину, называется THERMODO, это термометр для andorid и ios который работает через 3.5мм вход в девайсе.

Я даже в интернете нашел схему как оно работает
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но я хоть убей не понимаю как они это сделали? 
Я понимаю что тут используется терморезистор с резистором, все это каким-то образом припаяно к 3.5 мм разъему, и на девайсе идет уже распознование сигнала или напряжения или чего-то, что отдает этот терморезистор... Может кто нибудь дорисовать на схеме как и что паять, куда и почем пожалуйста. И какой сигнал я буду получать в телефон, что бы хотя бы примерно понимать что мне нужно будет обрабатывать...

Comment: Что, никто не знает?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дисклеймер: паять не умею, и как устроен 3.5 мм разъем не знаю. Знаю, что него должны быть вход и выход.

Из схемы видно, что

- Телефон подает на разъем известное постоянное напряжение V<sub>in</sub>
- Телефон снимает с разъема напряжение V<sub>out</sub>

Со школы известно, что ток через последовательные сопротивления Z<sub>1</sub> и Z<sub>2</sub> идет одинаковый, т.е. (V<sub>in</sub> - V<sub>out</sub>)/Z<sub>1</sub> = V<sub>out</sub>/Z<sub>2</sub>.

Зная V<sub>in</sub>, V<sub>out</sub> и Z<sub>1</sub>, вычисляем Z<sub>2</sub>, и по нему температуру.

Дорисовывать, по-моему, ничего не надо. Разве что землю общую.

Comment: Спасибо стало немного понятней

Comment: Но как объеденить эту схему с 3.5мм разъмом все так же не понятно)